# How can I create 1 seamless tab file for master map?

Tags: mapinfo, os-mastermap, seamless

This is my first post on here so please excuse if it's in the wrong place.

I've processed some mastermap files which display absolutely fine. However, during the processing it would not let me create just 1 seamless tab file as the index was over 2Gb. I therefore had to split it in to attributes, i.e. Topo_Point_Seamless, Carto_Area_Seamless etc.

Now although these work if you load them all separately, it makes it more awkward to work with. Ideally I'd like just 1 seamless tab file i can turn on and off in MapInfo and geoset's etc. However i've tried the seamless creator in MapInfo (11.5) but it says I cannot create a seamless file from other Seamless files.

Does anyone know how i could go about this?

Many thanks,

Nick

Comment: Sorry, I've amended it so it actually makes sense now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite a seamless table but will kind of function as one:

Open all your MasterMap seamless tables.
In layer control, right click the title of the map (the top most item) and select "Add group"
Add your MM layers to this group and rename it to MasterMap.
Save as a workspace.

You can then use the workspace as a sort of seamless layer with the added benefit of being able to switch off individual layers e.g carto_text or all layers at once.

Comment: Thanks for that BStone, that'll certainly help within mapinfo at least although it still leaves me with MapX geoset manager using individual items. I'm using Interpose to create the seamless tables. Which says it's unable to create a seamless table larger than 2Gb, hence splitting it in to feature groups. Perhaps this is where I'm going wrong? Is there a program that will create seamless tab files larger than 2Gb?

Comment: I believe the 2gb limit is a MapInfo limit so you can't get around that with other software. You could strip out any  attribute data you don't need to reduce file size, but not sure if interpose allows you to do so before it processes. You could do it manually yourself afterwards so you are left with several tables all under 2gb, e.g Topo_line, Topo_area, Carto_text etc, you could then create a seamless table from just these tabs. The next problem would be that all those TABs must have the same table structure.